# Replace Backslash when converting to JSON Array in Azure Logic App

Tags: azure-logic-apps, backslash, json-arrayagg

I am trying to fetch a JSON Array, however the Logic App Response it itself is appending a backslash to the response.
Output expected :- {
"ABC": [
"000D",
"100D",
"1200D"
]
}
I am getting response like below
[image: picture]

I am trying to use Replace function but it is not allowing to have replace function for array output.
Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this ...

##### Test Flow

[image: Test Flow]

The expression in that second step is ...

```
json(replace(string(variables('JSON')), '\"', ''))
```

... which in simple terms is doing the following ...

1. Converting the object to a string.
2. Replacing all of the escaped quotes with an empty string.
3. Converting the string back to a JSON object.

##### Result

[image: Result]

Answer (score 0):

After reproducing from my end, I could able to get this done by converting the array to string and then use replace function. Below is the flow of my logic app.

[image]

[image]

Results:

[image]